# driver build is failing for amd64 via winddk

Tags: wdk

I am building driver using winddk after setting the env as below:
setenv.bat fre wxp amd64

But while running the build command getting below error:

1>NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINDDK\3790~1.183\lib\wxp\amd64\BufferOverflowK.lib'

Though for i386 BufferOverflowk.lib is present under i386 folder of winddk installation path but the same is not present under amd64 folder.
Can anybody explain me why is that so and what's the work around for it.
Regards,
Dheeraj