# fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\lib\wxp\i386\msvcrt_winxp.obj'

Tags: c++, build-error, wdk

I try to compile a driver for WinXP x86 Release, using these commands:

```
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.0\bin\setenv.bat C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.0\ fre x86 WXP no_oacr
cd C:\src
build
```

It fails because of these U1073 errors about msvcrt_winxp.obj. I checked and there is no msvcrt_winxp.obj file anywhere in `C:\WinDDK` or its subdirectories.

It looks to me the problem is not in the actual code, but maybe I haven't set up the DDK right before compiling. Why do I get these U1073 errors?

I found this similar question - [driver build is failing for amd64 via winddk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857515/driver-build-is-failing-for-amd64-via-winddk), but there the OP did has not included relevant information such as his build output, and his question is unanswered. I also found this thread - http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-device-drivers/295015-wdk-linker-error-u1073.html, but there is no answer there, as well.

### My Build Output:

```
BUILD: Compile and Link for x86
BUILD: Loading c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\build.dat...
BUILD: Computing Include file dependencies:
BUILD: Start time: Thu Nov 13 12:04:25 2014
BUILD: Examining c:\src directory tree for files to compile.
    c:\src 
    c:\src\common 
    c:\src\driver 
    c:\src\ui 
BUILD: Saving c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\build.dat...
1>BUILD: Compiling (NoSync) c:\src\driver directory
2>BUILD: Compiling (NoSync) c:\src\ui directory
_NT_TARGET_VERSION SET TO WINXP
_NT_TARGET_VERSION SET TO WINXP
1>BUILD: Linking for c:\src\driver directory
2>BUILD: Linking for c:\src\ui directory
_NT_TARGET_VERSION SET TO WINXP
_NT_TARGET_VERSION SET TO WINXP
1>errors in directory c:\src\driver
1>NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\lib\wxp\i386\msvcrt_winxp.obj'
2>errors in directory c:\src\ui
2>NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\lib\wxp\i386\msvcrt_winxp.obj'
1>nmake.exe /nologo BUILDMSG=Stop. -i /nologo /f c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\bin\makefile.def BUILD_PASS=PASS2 LINKONLY=1 NOPASS0=1 MAKEDLL=1 MAKEDIR_RELATIVE_TO_BASEDIR= failed - rc = 2
2>nmake.exe /nologo BUILDMSG=Stop. -i /nologo /f c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\bin\makefile.def BUILD_PASS=PASS2 LINKONLY=1 NOPASS0=1 MAKEDLL=1 MAKEDIR_RELATIVE_TO_BASEDIR= failed - rc = 2
BUILD: Finish time: Thu Nov 13 12:04:26 2014
BUILD: Done
    0 files compiled - 4 Errors
```

Comment: WDK version 7600 was released in 2010, it targets Windows 7 and Server 2008.  That doesn't jive very well with "this is an old project" and targeting XP, surely you'll need to use the WDK version that the original programmer used to avoid makefile errors.  Whatever that might be, you leave no breadcrumbs.  Fwiw, building msvcrt.dll should only ever be done by a Microsoft machine.

Comment: OK, version `7600.16385.0` does support WinXP, if it didn't, this line `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.0\bin\setenv.bat C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.0\ fre x86 WXP no_oacr` would have failed. In fact, I just checked it, and if I replaced WXP with WXP2, it fails. So XP is supported. Also, I'm the old programmer, but it was 3 years ago since I've touched it, so yeah, it might as well be someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but after I installed an even newer version - `7600.16385.1` from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800, building worked fine, without any errors.

It didn't work the first time, however, but I noticed it was still complaining about `7600.16385.0`, so I removed any intermediary build output, .err and .log files. After compiling again, it worked this time.

I also noticed that `msvcrt_winxp.obj` was present in `c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1`, but not in `c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.0`.

I must admit that I hadn't downloaded `c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.0`, it was an old folder I found on my hard-drive, and I assumed I had used it to compile the project before, so I just copied it. The problems might have been because of this.

So in conclusion, the problem was with my WinDDK install, not with the project itself, and installing a newer version fixed it. Maybe re-installing the same version would have worked, too, but I have no need to verify that now that's working with the newer version.